# Redirecting on server side in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

*If this question is unclear or doesn't belong here/is duplicate,let me know.*

I have run two servers:one (*Apache*) on port 80,and second (custom) on port 81.
Now,the custom server is used for some scripting and **only listening on /cgi-bin/**

Now,i *ported* my Apache server to a custom url *abc.xyz*,and added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect "/cgi-bin/" "http://127.0.0.1:81/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

However,as i go on *abc.xyz/cgi-bin/somescript*,it redirects me to *localhost:81/cgi-bin/somescript* **on client side**.
And as you know,the server on localhost can be acessed only through my computer.

It is somehow possible to redirect a request on server side instead of client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not for Apache to serve a redirect, but for Apache to act as a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

`ProxyPass "/cgi-bin/"  "http://127.0.0.1:81/cgi-bin/"` should work for you.

Comment: I tried to do like ServerRoot `"C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPass "/cgi-bin/"  "http://127.0.0.1:81/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so` but it didn't worked.

Comment: When i go to 'http://127.0.0.1:81/cgi-bin/glq.cgi',it returns 'false'. But when i go to ''http://127.0.0.1:80/cgi-bin/glq.cgi' it shows 'Error 500',something like the server is overloaded or there is an error in CGI script. Note that CGI scripts on port 81 shows the output not the source code of the script.

Comment: FIXED! I had to add 'LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so' and '<IfModule mod_proxy_html.c>'